# asp.net OnPreRender doesn't fire after a Redirect in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, caching

When I run the following logic:

1) from Page1.aspx

```
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?Params...")
```

2) from Page2.aspx Page_Load event

```
Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx")
```

The Page1 OnPreRender event does not fire if the browser is IE8. Its ok with Firefox.

It seems that the browser is loading a cached version of the page.

Any idea how to force IE work like FF?

Thanks

Eduardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disable caching on your page Pageq.aspx by using `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`
 in Page_load

Comment: Vinay, thanks. Just to correct the typo: Pageq.aspx = Page1.aspx